# Уточнения с тире

Tags: пунктуация

Все чаще вижу конструкции предложений, в которые вклинены двойные тире, но сам с ними ещё не разобрался.

Например, такое предложение:

"Средний бюджет AAA-проекта — как правило, речь об играх, выпускаемых крупнейшими компаниями-издателями, продающихся на физических носителях и нередко входящих в состав известной серии из нескольких игр — колеблется от 18 до 24 млн долларов".

По какому правилу здесь располагаются тире? Это, полагаю, что-то вроде уточнений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не что то вроде, а как раз самое настоящее уточнение. Можете опираться на это правило:

> § 174. Посредством тире выделяются: 1. Предложения и слова,
>   вставляемые в середину предложения с целью пояснения или дополнения
>   его...

Если в месте расположения вставки нужны запятые для закрытия оборотов (что, который, если, деепричастие, причастие), то они должны быть поставлены. Тире не "съедает" запятые. Это два независимых знака.

В принципе, в любом таком контексте допускается применить вместо тире и скобки  — решение за автором.

Comment: Каков правильный порядок постановки тире и не "съеденной" запятой? Если завтра будет тепло - в чем я сильно сомневаюсь - , (, -) то мы пойдем на море. Если уточнение оформить знаком тире, то как правильно поставить запятую?

Comment: @John Smith  запятая всегда ставится перед тире. Для себя мы понимаем, что, по логике математика, оборот с тире входит внутрь оборота с запятой, но есть нормы для типографии, согласно которым, запятую нельзя поставить за тире.

Answer (score 4):

Это правило можно найти у Розенталя ([**вставные предложения и словосочетания**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125)):

4. В зависимости от синтаксической структуры предложения и вставной конструкции на месте «разрыва» основного предложения, **помимо тире, могут быть еще запятые.**

Здесь возможны следующие случаи:

1) **с обеих сторон ставится только тире,** если в месте вставки дополнительных сведений не должно быть никакого знака препинания:
*Аннушка молча покинула свою засаду, тихо обошла кругом — **её детские ножки едва шумели по густой траве** — и вышла из чащи подле самого старика* (Т.).

Это как раз ваш случай.